# Tooltip doesn't work properly with any Element not using :active state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on top">
  Tooltip on top
</button>

<a href='#' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on top">
  Tooltip on top
</a>

<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on top">
  Tooltip on top
</span>
```

In both `<button>` and `<a>`, When i click the `Tooltip` stays `shown`, But for `<span>` it only occurs on `hover` only.

I've tried it on `Opera Mobile Emulator`, Sometimes the `Tooltip` doesn't `disappear` after clicking on anything outside the `Tooltip` Element,

Am I using it wrong or something?

I want it simply to be `shown` on `hover` and stay on `click`, But if i clicked outside it or its element to `disappear`, And for Mobile since there is no `Hover`, To stay `shown` on `click` and hide on `outside click` for the `<span>` element, or do i have to use `<button>` and `<a>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I using it wrong or something?

No, I don't think so. You are talking about the `Opera Mobile Emulator` and that is probably trying to emulate Opera Mini. And Opera Mini is notorious for NOT supporting many, MANY of the modern CSS3 features.

Whenever I check on https://caniuse.com whether or not a particular css feature is supported, Opera Mini is almost always "red" which means "unsupported".

My recommendation: Forget about Opera Mini; not worth it. But that's just my personal opinion. I think I answered your question above. The Tooltips from your code work perfectly in my current browser (Chrome).

Quote from https://caniuse.com :

> In most cases Opera Mini processing is done via Opera servers, which often prevents JS from working correctly.

That says it all.

Comment: The `<span>` stays `shown` if clicked on it? It doesn't  at `Firefox`, I'll try `NOX App Player` to Emulate Smart Devices, Or is there a better Emulator? Since i want to check the `Touch Events`

Comment: In my case, none of them stay shown. They disappear as soon as move my mouse out.

Comment: I tested it now on `Chrome`, After i click on `<button>` or `<a>` the `tooltip` stays and the `<span>` doesn't as `Firefox` .

Comment: Just tested in 5 different browsers (Chrome, Opera Desktop, Firefox, Edge and IE) and everywhere all 3 of your tooltips show up as expected and disappear as expected. Absolutely no problems. Are you testing touch versions only?

Comment: I didn't test it on `touch devices` now since i don't have an `Emulator`, My comments was about PC Web browsers, But if it works correctly on `Mobile` Web Browsers then i guess my problem was the `Emulator`.

Comment: It's almost certainly the emulator. I cannot detect anything abnormal.